ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject
Возникает ошибка при попытке добавить зависимость spring-security-oauth2-client.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:164) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]

json-smart добавлен в зависимости
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'net.minidev:json-smart:2.5.1'
    ...
}

Так же в проект подключен bom: org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom
api(enforcedPlatform('org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom:7.20.0'))

И подключена соответствующая зависимость camunda.spin.dataformat:
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'camunda.spin.dataformat'
    implementation 'net.minidev:json-smart:2.5.1'
    ...
}

Обратил внимание на то что внутри используется конструкция relocations ( https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/3f6cb3055232c0fa9958e7a351af6ea0eafd7bb2/spin/dataformat-all/pom.xml#L79 )
pom.xml:
...
<relocations>
    <relocation>
      <pattern>net.minidev</pattern>
      <shadedPattern>spinjar.com.minidev</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
    ...
</relocations>
...

И действительно JSONObject можно вызвать по пути spinjar.com.minidev.json.JSONObject.
Как можно провернуть этот фарш назад ? Чтобы spinjar.com.minidev.json.JSONObject стал снова net.minidev.json.JSONObject ?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Убрал скрин. Добавил пример с relocation текстом.

Если класс JSONObject находится в пакете spinjar.com.minidev.json, то по какой причине выполняется попытка загрузить класс net.minidev.json.JSONObject? Используя ту информацию, которую Вы предоставили, на мой взгляд, невозможно однозначно ответить на Ваш вопрос.

@XelaNimed, отвечаю на ваш вопрос.
Возникает ошибка при попытке добавить зависимость spring-security-oauth2-client.
Т.е. когда добавляю новую зависимость, проект перестает стартовать. При этом трассировка ошибки в самом верху сообщения говорит в каком месте все падает.

Чуть ниже писал что проблема, кажется, заключается relocations в зависимости org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom. Т.е. я ожидал, что если я добавлю implementation 'net.minidev:json-smart:2.5.1' в проект, то проблема уйдет. Но был не прав. Эта библиотека и так есть в проекте но она перенесена в другую группу. Как вернуть ее назад или что можно еще сделать я не понимаю.

Оказалось, что я сам себе навредил.
Когда то исключил данную либу ( json-smart ) из проекта.
И причем исключил по одному только называнию зависимости. И забыл.
...
  configurations {
    configureEach {
      ...
      exclude module: 'json-smart'
      ...
    }
  }
...


Искал где исключается зависимость и искал по названию группы net.minidev. Соответственно ничего не мог найти. Нашел ту штуку с <relocations>, сделал неправильные вывод и запутался.
Убрал лишний exclude и все заработало.
